# XBell not working

Tags: audio, x11, kde-plasma

The X11 system bell does not work. I don't get any sound on xterm (e.g., echo \\007) nor when I call XBell(), for example, in the following program:

```
Display *display=XOpenDisplay(NULL);

XBell(display, 1000);
XFlush(display);
```

xset gives the correct settings for bell sounds, but this doesn't seem to have any effect. I do get a bell sound in konsole. It plays a sound file (bell.oga). If I could get X to play this sound that would be just fine.

I found out that the pulseaudio configuration has a line commented-out that is relevant to the bell sound (referring to x11-bell module). What pulseaudio is supposed to do here is to catch bell events and play the sound. I uncommented it and tweaked it a little and it still doesn't work, though now suddenly firefox makes bell sounds in certain situations which it didn't do before (which means that something did change).

Any idea how I can find out where the bell events get lost on the way?

I have KDE 4.3.4 running on CentOS release 6.5, Linux 2.6.32.

Comment: This has nothing to to with X or audio programming. Your PC speaker was probably disabled. Check your ALSA settings and/or pcspkr kernel module.

Comment: Thanks, but I was hoping to get the bell event capturing mechanism to work so that the beep come out of the sound system and not the PC speaker. Any idea how?